# Javascript, JQuery and now AngularJS What is happening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have been away from computers for about 3 years and starting to get back into programming. Lots has changed in resources and help sites available on the web especially the evolving StackExchange community. I come from the IRC #javascript, #html, #php days with php.net and a bit of google search finds here and there.

With that said, before I took my break from programming JQuery was around but not nearly as common as today. I personally stay away from it finding it easier to just write what I need done in traditional javascript.

Now I have just stumbled across AngularJS. I do not know much about it, just looked at the home page and saw a few script samples.

My question is:

Am I hindering my clients by using javascript while being ignorant to JQuery and/or AngularJS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advantages of using pure JavaScript over JQuery](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/166273/advantages-of-using-pure-javascript-over-jquery)

Comment: short answer is you are hindering yourself by reinventing the wheel over and over and over and over.

Comment: how am i writing code over and over and over again, for example, i am using my xmlhttp request script from 10 years ago with some modifications, but it still does the job.

Comment: @N0M3 assembly does the job, but you don't see too many people programming in assembly these days. same goes for javascript, it's the assembly language of the browser. you can't really replace it so you're left with extending it. that's why we get frameworks like jQuery and Angular and languages like TypeScript.

Comment: they told me to ask that question here, that is too funny

Comment: I don't know why people throwing so much hate on the OP.. as if downvoting and closing the question isn't enough! That's what I hate the most in SE

Comment: you're missing the point, *React.js* is what you might want to pay more attention to ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you're writing a lot of bare Javascript code to perform functions that are already well-served (or perhaps better served) by the libraries.

In the specific case of jQuery, it is specifically designed to provide a library of useful functions *in a cross-browser independent way.*  So if you're writing a lot of hackish code to get around browser incompatibilities, jQuery can especially useful in that regard.

Libraries like AngularJS perform (among other things) a *binding/templating* function; that is, they allow you to bind data to your web page so that it is displayed in the page.  In addition, Angular provides support for several modern software patterns and a significant amount of sensible architecture.

What does this buy you?  *Leverage,* especially if you're writing even a moderately-sized web application.  Leverage means writing larger, more stable, more easily maintainable applications.

Comment: I'm just lucky to have been able to control the clients browser. I've been programming using xmlhttp since ie6. Now that I'm back in the game Firefox or Chrome are my new browsers of chose. As for AngularJS, I do not think it falls in the same category as jQuery. It seems to be more data orientated and I feel obligated to take a closer look at it. As for jQuery, I feel sorry for people who think they are learning javascript using jQuery, imo it is a complete joke.

Comment: jQuery is not intended to replace Javascript.  All it does is add some useful cross-browser-compatible utility functions.  Anyone who's trying to write browser applications solely using jQuery is doing it wrong.

Comment: ya, I'm satisfied with not using jQuery or AngularJS, one thing that has come out of the little bit of research I have done is `HTML5 Web Storage`. Now that is cool.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should ask yourself if there is a reason you **shouldn't** stay up to date on current technologies in your field.  I think that is part of being a good software developer, and it allows you to make more informed decisions.

Choosing not to use a framework because it doesn't work for your situation is one thing, but staying ignorant to them, I think, is detrimental to you **and** your clients.

Comment: This is a little vague.  Think you could short up your question a bit by providing some examples where the use of libraries might benefit both the OP and his clients?

Comment: I was trying to keep it a bit more vague and agnostic to the frameworks mentioned, but I guess that's probably not great for an answer.  I probably could provide some specific examples, but I think you have already addressed that better than I could have in your answer :)